# Gnuplot animation, how to print text from data file to graph

Tags: file, animation, printing, gnuplot

I want to plot columns 1 and 2, and print column 3 from a data file, however I cannot find how to directly read from the data file into `x` or into an array `x(n)`, basically the operation is this:

```
do for[j=0:n:1]{
    unset label
    x = #row j, column 3 of 'file-name.dat'
    set label x at 2000, 4000 ...
    plot 'file-name.dat' u 1:2 ....
}
```

Comment: Please clarify what exactly you want to appear in the plot. gnuplot is perfectly capable of plotting text from a data file directly via the `with labels` plot style.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is not very clear. Please always provide example data. How does your data look like and what exactly do you want to plot? Do you want to plot the complete column 1 and 2 or just the row `j`? Check the following example and check `help every` and `help labels`.

**Code:**

```
### plotting labels for animation
reset session

set term gif animate delay 50
set output "SO70101046.gif"

$Data <<EOD
0   0   Time0
1   1   Time1
2   2   Time2
3   3   Time3
4   4   Time4
5   5   Time5
EOD

stats $Data nooutput   # get the number of rows
N = STATS_records

set xrange[-1:6]
set yrange[-1:6]

do for [j=0:N-1] {
    plot $Data u 1:2 every ::j::j w lp pt 7 title "Data", \
         ''    u (0):(5):3 every ::j::j w labels notitle
}
set output
### end of code
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: Thanks!!!! I changed column 3 in the data file from floats to strings and your solution worked.

Comment: @akvadiv glad to hear. On StackOverflow: Upvote=answer was helpful, Accept=answer solved the problem.